# Annotations in django with model managers

Tags: django, annotations

I have two models with an one to many relation.
One model named repairorder, which can have one or more instances of work that is performed on that order.

What I need is to annotate the Repairorder queryset to sum the cummulative Work duration. On the Work model I annotated the duration of a single Work instance based on the start and end date time stamps. Now I need to use this annotated field to sum the total cummulative Work that is performed for each order. I tried to extend the base model manager:

```
from django.db import models

class WorkManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(OrderholdManager, self).get_queryset().annotate(duration=ExpressionWrapper(Coalesce(F('enddate'), Now()) - F('startdate'), output_field=DurationField()))


class Work(models.Model):
    #...
    order_idorder = models.ForeignKey('Repairorder', models.DO_NOTHING)
    startdate = models.DateTimeField()
    enddate = models.DateTimeField()
    objects = WorkManager()


class RepairorderManager(models.Manager):
      def get_queryset(self):
          return super(RepairorderexternalManager, self).get_queryset().annotate(totalwork=Sum('work__duration'), output_field=DurationField())


class Repairorder(models.Model):
   #...
   idrepairorder = models.autofield(primary_key=True)
   objects = RepairorderManager()
```

For each Repairorder I want to display the 'totalwork', however this error appears: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): . and if I remove the output_field=DurationField() from the RepairorderMananager, it says: Cannot resolve keyword 'duration' into field.

Doing it the 'Python way' by using model properties is not an option with big datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the calculation to the `RepairorderManager` as well:

```
class RepairorderManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(RepairorderexternalManager, self).get_queryset().annotate(
            totalwork=ExpressionWrapper(
                Sum(Coalesce(F('work__enddate'), Now()) - F('work__startdate')),
                output_field=DurationField()
            )
        )
```

Django does *not* take into account annotations introduced by manager on related objects.

Comment: Note that `queryset.annotate(...)` returns an annotated queryset, it does not modify the queryset in place. This is why Willem's nested style works. If multiple annotations that depend on each other are used, your code should be nested or use multiple lines of Djano's `queryset = queryset.annotate(...)` pattern.